# How to install cakephp on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, web-server, php

I tried to install cakephp on Raspberry Pi but failed to do so. I don't know how to configure LAMP on Rpi. Has anyone successfully done so?

I have developed a cakephp app on Windows running on WAMP server. I would prefer to have it running on a cheap Rpi.

Comment: Hello and welcome! What OS are you running on the Pi (though it shouldn't make a big difference).

Comment: I am using Raspbian

Comment: LAMP = **Linux** Apache MySQL PHP; it is not RPiAMP and the exact brand of hardware you are using is irrelevant. You would do this the same way on a laptop, blade server, whatever, which makes it [off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.  There must be thousands of how-tos and tutorials on-line, as well as a mountain of books around if you are near a library.  If you have any trouble with that material, feel free to ask a specific question on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The [normal install](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp) procedure;

```
apt-get install -y php5-cli
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

works. What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @SteveRobillard good point, fixed.

Comment: I removed the migration portion of your answer. The proper way to handle that would be to vote to close and choose off topic and if it belongs on another SO site indicate that.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, That's all well and good but I have never seen a question actually migrated so I like to keep the note in the answer until after it's actually migrated. (also shows I agree it should be migrated vs there being some unexpected hardware specific issue)

Comment: Please do not add those types of notes. First only mods can migrate a question ... and there are good reasons for this. If there are others I would ask that you remove them as well. As I said you can show your agreement by voting to close as I stated. FYI plenty of questions are/have been migrated.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, even when it's "to old to migrate" you don't think it's a good idea to show new users what is considered off topic?

Comment: That's what `close` votes are for, which you are [entitled to cast](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).   We don't have that big a community, and getting the prerequisite 5 votes may take some time unless a moderator (or someone with a gold badge on one of the tags) votes, which is decisive.   As a mod I sometimes feel this is heavy handed, so I have to refrain from voting, but I will start going through [the review queue](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review) (something you can do too) more often looking for particularly bad examples.

Comment: Lets continue this in chat